# How to save "Shipping address" to fill it automatically every time I go to Stripe Checkout with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments, python-stripe-api

I set [shipping_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection) in **Django View** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

import stripe
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def test(request):
    customer = stripe.Customer.search(query="email:'test@gmail.com'", limit=1)
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        customer=customer["data"][0]["id"] if customer['data'] else None,
        line_items=[
            {
                "price_data": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                    "product_data": {
                        "name": "T-shirt",
                    },
                },
                "quantity": 2,
            }
        ],
        payment_method_options={ 
            "card": {
                "setup_future_usage": "on_session",
            },
        }, # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
        shipping_address_collection={
            "allowed_countries": ['US']
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://localhost:8000',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:8000'
    )

    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

But, I need to fill **Shipping address** of **Shipping information** manually every time I go to **Stripe Checkout** because it is not saved while **Payment details** is saved with [setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_method_options-card-setup_future_usage) as shown below:

[image]

So now, how can I save **Shipping address** to fill it automatically every time I go to **Stripe Checkout**?

Is there like `setup_future_usage` for **Shipping address** to fill it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

When using Stripe Checkout, it's not possible to prefill a customer's shipping address. You can prefill customer email address and, if you [pass an ID for `customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer), you can prefill a previously-saved payment method and its associated billing address.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I could save **Shipping address** to fill it automatically every time I go to **Stripe Checkout** as shown below:

[image]

What I did is to delete the customers whose email is `test@gmail.com` in **Customers** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can use [payment_intent_data.shipping](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-shipping) to pass a shipping address to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below. *This doesn't pass a shipping address to **Stripe Checkout** but does pass to **Shipping** section in **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** and you cannot use both `payment_intent_data.shipping` and [shipping_address_collection](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection) at the same time otherwise there is an error:

```py
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  ...
  payment_intent_data={
    "shipping": {
      "name": "John Smith",
      "address": {
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "California",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "line1": "58 Middle Point Rd",
        "line2": "",
        "postal_code": "94124"
      }
    }
  },
  # shipping_address_collection={
  #     "allowed_countries": ['US']
  # },
  ...
});
```

[image]